# How to ask for appropriate pay higher than initially negotiated?

Tags: salary, job-offer, new-job

About 3 months back, I got a call for an opportunity and they asked for the expected salary. I agreed for X dollars. Last week, I saw the same job posting on a different site with offered salary bracket from [X to X+2].

Today after getting confirmed by their client, they send a drafted version of Offer mentioning X dollars as pay which is the lowest limit I had requested.
I know, my entire interview performance was great and I am a good fit for the client, but *how do I ask the contractor to give me a better pay than what I agreed initially without sounding greedy and rude?*

Comment: "I agreed for X dollars [...] the lowest limit I requested". Could you clarify - did you agree to X dollars, or to a range? If you agreed to X dollars, what did you expect to get as an offer?

Comment: I agreed for X dollars for the given job during the initial screening phase. However while attempting for a different position I asked for an additional 500 dollars a month and they agreed. Now, I know I can get that much paid and not willing to settle for less for one full year.

Comment: @RupaMistry if it was a different position it's a whole 'nother story. It's a different job, contract, perhaps even company, etc. The fact that for that job they agreed to give you an extra 500 does not mean that on this other job it will happen like that.

Comment: @DarkCygnus.. I understand. But I just want to get paid as per the market rate. I accept I asked for less fearing that I may not be able to even go through the screening process, but now I am no where in a win-win position.

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify such points, as it is a bit unclear now if it's one or two positions, etc. That way I can answer you better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it OK to ask for a higher salary than what you listed as your expected salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-a-higher-salary-than-what-you-listed-as-your-expected-salary)

Answer (score 2):

> I know, my entire interview performance was great and I am a good fit for the client, but how do I ask the contractor to give me a better pay than what I agreed initially without sounding greedy and rude?

I think that at this point you already "played your cards".

You already offered and even agreed on X salary. Asking now for X+n could be an inefficient move and could even a bit of bad taste, as you already sense.

This is part of the negotiating process. Sometimes one gets with more outcome and sometimes one ends up giving the lower limit (even unknowingly).

To put it under other light. What would you have done if you didn't found about this other page where you saw it was X+2? Most likely you would have taken it gladly, but now that you know you see you could have asked for more... but the time for doing that is past now.

Asking for more now will unlikely give you what you want (you could try, but most likely they will graciously refuse and insist on X).

Comment: I got the point. But I am not asking for X+2. I am asking for an additional 500 dollars which is very much the market rate and very much within their budget.

Comment: @RupaMistry then I think I misunderstood a bit, or your comments or post is a bit unclear. You mentioned in comments that "while attempting for a different position" you asked for those 500 extra... but that is a different position right? I think you are mixing two different situations, or are they the same? Please clarify

Comment: Two different situations..two different positions.. but same market.

Comment: Then, in that case, one negotiation process is completely independent to the other... now, is X under market rate for *this* position? Why did you ask for X in first place if in the other position you knew you had to ask 500 more?